# Adding new robots in robots section

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
How can we add a new robot in ROS Wiki's Robots category?
We can see many robots under http://wiki.ros.org/Robots.
When we click on any of the robots (for ex. "RobotXYZ"). It takes me to a page  http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/RobotXYZ.
My question is... How do can we have our robot page appear under Robots category?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233822/adding-new-robots-in-robots-section/) by [Anant](https://answers.ros.org/users/26791/anant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to get a wiki account, then you can edit that page or any other page. Here is how you sign up http://wiki.ros.org/FAQ#How_do_I_get_a_Wiki_account.3F_Can_I_edit_pages_on_ROS.org

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anant](https://answers.ros.org/users/26791/anant/) on 2016-05-08**:
Thank you for your response.... Let me clarify
We can see many robots under http://wiki.ros.org/Robots.
When we click on any of the robots (for ex. "RobotXYZ"). It takes me to a page  http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/RobotXYZ.
My question is... How do can we have our robot appear under Robots category?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-05-09**:
Once you're created a wiki page for your robot, edit the Robots page to add a link for your robot. You can see how this is done in the [raw view of http://wiki.ros.org/Robots](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots?action=raw)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-28**:
Note that this has been moved to robots.ros.org and now has a [contribution guide](http://robots.ros.org/contributing/)